# Javascript. Elements of array initialization order

Tags: javascript, arrays, specifications

One day I saw certain way to swap elements in array. Like this:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3];
arr[0] = [arr[1], arr[1] = arr[0]][0];
```

Obviously this method assume that first value of temporary array `arr[1]` will be calculated before second `arr[1] = arr[0]`.
Otherway both values will be the same. Synthetic example:

```js
var x = 1;
var arr = [x, x += 1, x += 1];
arr; // [1,2,3] or [3,3,2] or maybe [3,2,3]?
```

Is there any guarantees that javascript interpreter will not act in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS array initializers are guaranteed to be evaluated left-to-right

> ArrayAccumulation(ElementList : ElementList , Elision[opt] AssignmentExpression):
>
> .1. Let postIndex be the result of performing ArrayAccumulation for ElementList with arguments array and nextIndex...
>
> .4. Let initResult be the result of evaluating AssignmentExpression.

@http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-arrayaccumulation

It's better not to rely on that though.

Comment: "*It's better not to rely on that though.*" - Huh? You absolutely can rely on it.